# Apache management: extract hostname and virtual host IP address from an Apache config file

Tags: shell, apache, awk

I need to manage domain names (fqdn), printing all of them somewhere, possibly in a file csv. All infos are in apache conf files, I need to associate all the domain name with ip and port.
This is the sample file. You can have the same fqdn both in servername an serveralias, there could be some trailing spaces between two parameters, some comments (#). Here the sample file:

```xml
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-6.mydomain.example.org_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/www.example.com/www.example.com_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName gimbo.customexample.org
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/gimbo.customexample.org/gimbo.customexample.org_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-6.mydomain.example.org_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-6.mydomain.example.org_ssl_access_log 86400" customssl
IncludeOptional conf.d/star_mydomain_example_org.cnf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:8080>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
ServerAlias www.example.org www.pollo.biz www.pollone.mondo
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-6.mydomain.example.org_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-7.mydomain.example.org/host-7.mydomain.example.org_access_log 86400" customssl
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-7.mydomain.example.org/host-7.mydomain.example.org_ssl_error_log 86400"
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/host-7.mydomain.example.org/host-7.mydomain.example.org_ssl_access_log 86400" customssl
IncludeOptional conf.d/star_mydomain_example_org.cnf
</VirtualHost>
```

These are the domains (fqdn)

```
gimbo.customexample.org
host-6.mydomain.example.org
host-7.mydomain.example.org
www.example.biz
www.example.com
www.example.org
www.pollo.biz
www.pollone.mondo
```

I need this output (sort and uniq are not necessary, the output will be processed later):

```
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.biz,10.11.12.21,80
gimbo.customexample.org,10.11.12.21,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
www.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollo.biz,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollone.mondo,10.11.12.22,8080
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
```

What I tried:

```bash
awk -v n=2 -e '/^\s*Server(Name|Alias)/ { for (i=n; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s",   $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' $1 | awk -v RS='[\n ]' '{print}'
```

Now I can print all the fqdn.
How can I add the correct ip address an the port?

Comment: You need a variable to store the IP address when you match `$1 = "<VirtualHost"`, ready for use in the subsequent line(s).

Comment: Can we assume that the 8th line of your input sample (`www.example.biz`) really belongs to the previous line?

Comment: pardon, typo error, I fix it now ...

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }

$1 == "<VirtualHost" {
    split($2,tmp,/:/)
    ip   = tmp[1]
    port = tmp[2]+0
}

$1 ~ /^Server(Name|Alias)$/ {
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        fqdns[$i]
    }
}

$1 == "</VirtualHost>" {
    for ( fqdn in fqdns ) {
        print fqdn, ip, port
        delete fqdns[fqdn]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com,10.11.12.21,80
gimbo.customexample.org,10.11.12.21,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollo.biz,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollone.mondo,10.11.12.22,8080
www.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that @Grobu's answer is far more elegant (and probably more efficient either), also the following should to the trick:

```
grep "\(<VirtualHost \|ServerName \|ServerAlias \)" sample.input \
| sed ':a;N;s/\nServerAlias / / ; ba' \
| sed 's/\(<VirtualHost \|ServerName \)//;s/:\(.*\)>/,\1/' \
| sed 's/ /\n/g' \
| while read line; do if [[ "$line" =~ .+,.+ ]]; then address=$line; else echo "$line,$address"; fi; done
```

...where:
**1st line** --> use grep to extract only VirtualHost, ServerName and ServerAlias lines. It produces:

```
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName gimbo.customexample.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:8080>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
ServerAlias www.example.org www.pollo.biz www.pollone.mondo
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
```

**2nd line** --> use sed to evaluate a line by setting a label (`:a;`) on the line, appending the next one with a '\n' (`N;`),  found replace "\nServerAlias " with a simple space (`s/\nServerAlias / / ;`), and finally restart the evaluation by jumping back to the label a (`ba`). It produces:

```
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName www.example.com www.example.com
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.21:80>
ServerName gimbo.customexample.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:8080>
ServerName host-6.mydomain.example.org www.example.org www.pollo.biz www.pollone.mondo
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:80>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.22:443>
ServerName host-7.mydomain.example.org
```

**3rd line** --> Delete every ServerName and VirtualHost occurrence (`s/\(<VirtualHost \|ServerName \)//`), replace ':' with ',' and delete the final '>' (`s/:\(.*\)>/,\1/`). It produces:

```
10.11.12.21,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com www.example.com
10.11.12.21,80
gimbo.customexample.org
10.11.12.22,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,443
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,8080
host-6.mydomain.example.org www.example.org www.pollo.biz www.pollone.mondo
10.11.12.22,80
host-7.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,443
host-7.mydomain.example.org
```

**4th line** --> use sed command to replace every space with a new line (`s/ /\n/g`), in order to obtain different server name/alias on different lines. It produces:

```
10.11.12.21,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com
www.example.com
10.11.12.21,80
gimbo.customexample.org
10.11.12.22,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,443
host-6.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,8080
host-6.mydomain.example.org
www.example.org
www.pollo.biz
www.pollone.mondo
10.11.12.22,80
host-7.mydomain.example.org
10.11.12.22,443
host-7.mydomain.example.org
```

**5th line** --> use a while-do loop to iterate every line (`while read line; do ...done`), temporary storing when matching a line with ip and port (the only lines that contain a comma: `if [[ "$line" =~ .+,.+ ]]; then address=$line;`) without printing it, and otherwise printing every other line by concatenating the stored ip and port (`else echo "$line,$address";`). It finally produces:

```
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com,10.11.12.21,80
www.example.com,10.11.12.21,80
gimbo.customexample.org,10.11.12.21,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
host-6.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
www.example.org,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollo.biz,10.11.12.22,8080
www.pollone.mondo,10.11.12.22,8080
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,80
host-7.mydomain.example.org,10.11.12.22,443
```

Comment: Please see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why not to use a shell read loop to process text and then how to do it as robustly as possible if you're going to do it anyway.